# Firewall start/stop using win32 api for windows XP os

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-xp, firewall

I am trying to start and stop the firewall in Windows XP using the win32 api for changing settings in the registry, i.e `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SharedAccess\Parameters\FirewallPolicy\StandardProfile`. I am trying to change a data value but it's not changing. So can tell me any other way how I can stop the firewall in windows XP?

Comment: Really bad idea to stop firewall. Why do you want to put your customer at risk?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you stopping the firewall? 
Did you check this article from [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/enable_disable_firewall.aspx) which uses another method?

Edit: Got this from [here](http://groups.google.ca/group/microsoft.public.windowsxp.security_admin/msg/33e4b45fc69581f0).

There are several solutions available to disable the firewall
programmatically without extracting the SP2 EXE file.

Here are two ways:

1) Adding the registry values mentioned, this can be done either
before or after SP2 is installed

The registry key path has changed since I posted that post (it is now WindowsFirewall instead of FirewallPolicy):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\DomainProfile
          \EnableFirewall=0 (DWORD data type)

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\StandardProfile
          \EnableFirewall=0 (DWORD data type)
```

If you want to disable the service as well:

sc.exe config SharedAccess start= disabled

2)The following command line will disable SP2's firewall (must be
run after SP2 is installed and at least one reboot is done):

```
netsh.exe firewall set opmode mode=disable profile=all
```

Comment: Thanks for replying .But i tried to change the Data value for StandardProfile\EnableFirewall , there showing that (invalid DWORD value) , so how can i change

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to netsh.exe, it looks very helpful for working with the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

What service pack are you running? Microsoft likes to relocate these keys ...  ;-)

Check

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\DomainProfile\EnableFirewall=0` (DWORD data type)

and

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsFirewall\StandardProfile\EnableFirewall=0` (DWORD data type)

Stopping the service would be best though ;-)